# Could I host a localhost VPN server to encrypt my traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I am an upcoming VPN provider, so I'm looking into everything you can do with a VPN.

One of my thoughts, was this idea...

If I install an openvpn server on my home desktop, and make an ovpn file that connects to 127.0.0.1, theoretically, could I encrypt my data like a vpn on an external ipv4? Would I be able to browse with my data encrypted as if it were on a regular VPN set-up?

Comment: for someone who is an "upcoming vpn" provider, you certainly dont know the basics of VPNs...

Answer (score 2):

No.

Data would be encrypted between the Open VPN client and server on your machine, and only between those two programs, which would serve no discernable purpose.

External data from VPN Server to public web is in the clear since public web servers would not be able to decrypt it otherwise.